# how to add multiple shared libraries in this makefile

Tags: makefile

I have a source file that uses two shared libs (i.e. -lnr2c and -lm). I would like to add the math lib `-lm` without `-l`. This is the part of my makefile for this matter.

```
LIBFILE    = nr2c -lm
INCLUDES   = -I$(INCLUDEDIR)
LIBS       = -L$(LIBDIR) -l$(LIBFILE)
```

I've tried this approach

```
LIBFILE    = nr2c m
```

and

```
LIBFILE    = nr2c / m
```

with no luck. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see *why* you want to do this, but here's a way:

```
LIBFILE = nr2c m
LIBS    = -L$(LIBDIR) $(addprefix -l, $(LIBFILE))
```

Comment: how to split these libs via newline splitter?

Comment: @CroCo: Do you mean that you want a newline in the command, between `-lnr2c` and `-lm`?

Comment: That can be done, but it doesn't play well with `addprefix`. Is there some *reason* you want to things in this weird way?

Comment: I have a lot of libs. I thought it would be nice if I separate them via a newline separator but if this will complicate the problem then I am happy with your answer.